# How can we distinguish meta-analysis and statistical analysis?

Tags: statistics, significance, meta-analysis

The two terms are frequently used in statistical methods. I find that statistical reasoning/ theory support meta analysis. What is real relation between two terms? Help me to understand the two concepts.

Comment: Normally a meta-analysis takes as input other analyses done by other researchers and draws conclusions based on their aggregate data.

Answer (score 0):

Meta-analysis uses effect-sizes generated by studies that use statistical methods to arrive at conclusions.It(meta-analysis) can be implemented to verify or generate inferences that is generalizations that are widely true across population subgroups and even a set of populations.On the contrary, statistical methods focus on an individual sample and use primary data to substantiate a particular hypothesis. It seems meta-analysis employs statistical theorems to validate a true effect across several subgroups and/or a for given population.In other words,Basic statistics embraces sampling theory and Advanced statistics focuses on inference. Meta-analysis is an Advanced Statistics Method that has a genesis in sampling theory and measures-theory. Being a naive statistician, I can not explain in technical terms.Hope, it serves my purpose of sharing knowledge.